# focus-out event in Ember.Select view

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have used `Ember.Select view` as follows.

```
{{view "select" content=people
                optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
                optionValuePath="content.id"
                prompt="Pick a person:"
                selection=selectedPerson}}
```

Now I want to add `focus-out="showErrors"` event listener to this select view in order to handle some validation. This works perfectly with `Ember.TextField and Ember.TextArea`. But I noticed the `focus-out` does not work with Ember.Select view.

It would be really nice if someone can provide a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Could you add an observer to selectedPerson so that when the user changes the dropdown value this will trigger your validation.

Older syntax:

```
validatePersonChange: function(){
   //do validation here
  }.observes('selectedPerson')
```

Newer syntax:

```
const { observer } = Ember;
...
validatePersonChange: observer('selectedPerson', function(){
    //do validation
  })
```